# MySQL Manager Script - Execute Multiple External Scripts Inside Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have one script that I want to use to execute multiple external scripts.  An example of this script looks like this:

```
source createTable1.sql
source insertTable1Data.sql
source createTable2.sql
```

`source` works fine from the MySQL command line, but it does not work inside MySQL Workbench.  Is there any command in MySQL Workbench (query window) that will allow me to execute an external script.

Answer (score -2):

The `source` command does not make sense in an environment where you can load and run scripts at will. In MySQL Workbench you simply open the individual scripts and run them. If enabled they even will be reopened when you restart MySQL Workbench and are then always at hand, if you need to run them frequently.

Use the toolbar to open a script in the editor.

Comment: I am trying to make a manager script that calls a bunch of little scripts.  For an example, I broke down 1 3000 line script down to 10 300 line scripts so they are easier to manage, and it's easier to run individual commands.  So if I only want to create the Employee tables, I just run that one script ... but if I want to create the whole database, I run the "manager" script (the one I can't figure out how to make).

Comment: As I wrote, this is not possible in MySQL Workbench, but you can file a feature request (http://bugs.mysql.com) for support of the "source" command.